# SSRS 2016 Does not open subscription page or let me add a subscription

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have spent a lot of time researching and trying to figure out this error in SSRS.  If I got to the subscriptions page I get a message saying "Something went wrong. Please try again later."  If I look at the logs for SSRS I see this:

" OData exception occurred: System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized."

Has anyone seen this error before and worked through it?  I have tried:

- Restoring the encryption key
- Changing the encryption key
- Deleting all subscriptions and encrypted data

The SSRS Site and the database server are on the same server so I cannot think it is a double hop/kerberos thing but maybe.

Anyone have any other ideas?

Thank you!

Jesse

Comment: Did it recently start doing this?  Any recent changes that you know of?

Comment: Also, check for any scheduled reports.

Comment: No very recent changes that seem impactful.  I did put in a procedure that adjusted emails on a subscription, however, when I delete that subscription the error is still there.

Comment: Anyone find a fix for this one?

Comment: Hey @Ross I never did find a solution.  I ended up creating a new reporting services instance, moved all reports over to it via the ssrs migration script I found on MS github page and moved everyone to the new site.